# How do I redraw a series on HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am attempting to redraw data on highcharts. I use this code to initialise the chart.

```
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
            events: {
                click: function(event) {
                    alert (
                    'x: '+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', event.xAxis[0].value) +', ' +
                    'y: '+ event.yAxis[0].value
                    );
                }
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Amount'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },

        plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        alert ('Category: '+ this.category +', value: '+ this.y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Expected',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'Received',
            data: [1.0, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }],
});
```

Using a HTML button, I call the following

```
Highcharts.chart.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4] );
```

It gives the following error

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Is it possible to update the chart this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the chart by globar variable Highcharts in this way:

```
Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].setData([...] );
```

Or store the chart in a variable:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {...});

chart.series[0].setData([...]);
```

Please note that you can manage the redrawing by a parameter of `setData` method.

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4902/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData

Answer (score 6):

First you need to store the chat object in a variable.

```
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
```

next

```
   chart.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4] );
```

finally you can redraw() a chart by:

```
    chart.redraw();
```

Please, take a look at the example below.

http://jsfiddle.net/d_paul/mo7ef7ey/

Answer (score 2):

To update a chart I usually do this:

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts(); //Div containing HighChart
chart.series[0].update({
    pointStart: newSeries[0].pointStart,
    data: newSeries[0].data
}, true); //true / false to redraw
```

PS: This would work post version 3.0.1.